# What can replace FocusTrap in flutter 3.7.0?

Tags: flutter, widget

I updated flutter to 3.7.0 and found that the FocusTrap widget has been removed.

What can I replace it with? for example source from pinput library:

```
return _PinputFormField(
      enabled: isEnabled,
      validator: _validator,
      child: FocusTrap(
        focusNode: effectiveFocusNode,
        child: MouseRegion(
          cursor: _effectiveMouseCursor,
          onEnter: (PointerEnterEvent event) => _handleHover(true),
          onExit: (PointerExitEvent event) => _handleHover(false),
          child: IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: !isEnabled || !widget.useNativeKeyboard,
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: _effectiveController,
              builder: (_, Widget? child) => Semantics(
                maxValueLength: widget.length,
                currentValueLength: _currentLength,
                onTap: widget.readOnly ? null : _semanticsOnTap,
                onDidGainAccessibilityFocus: handleDidGainAccessibilityFocus,
                child: child,
              ),
              child: _gestureDetectorBuilder.buildGestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  children: [
                    _buildEditable(textSelectionControls),
                    _buildFields(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The offical replacement is `TapRegionSurface`([flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TapRegionSurface-class.html)) and `TapRegion`

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/107262